# Laravel - LoginController | How to set $redirectTo route with parameters?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

In my `LoginController` I have defined a custom redirect route like this:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

which works fine but I want to show a toastr notification when user logs in therefore I want to `flash` some data with this redirect.

In my other controllers I'm doing something like this and it works good

```
$notification = array(
                        'message' => 'User okay', 
                        'alert_type' => 'success',
                      );
return Redirect::route('user')->with('notification', $notification);
```

but I can't figure out how to it with the `$redirectTo`

Please help me with this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to pass a "message bag", is to create a `redirectTo method` in the LoginController.

Out of the box this method is not present, because it is inherited from the **`trait RedirectsUsers`** so, just wrote it and complete as needed and it will be executed just when the user had been authenticated (as the function name say)

```
protected function redirectTo(Request $request)
{
    $notification = array(
        'message' => 'User okay', 
        'alert_type' => 'success',
    );
    return Redirect::route($this->redirectTo)->with('notification', $notification);
}
```

As you can see, the **`trait RedirectsUsers`** is looking for a defined `redirectTo function` or using the variable you define as `$redirectTo`

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (method_exists($this, 'redirectTo')) {
        return $this->redirectTo();
    }

    return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
}
```

Otherwise, if the parameters you would like to pass is a simple GET parameter, you can use the same authenticated function and set it with the parameters as you prefer, also dynamic params like

```
protected function redirectTo(Request $request)
{
    return redirect()->route('route.name', [param1 => value1, param2 => value2]);
}
```

For the redirect purpose this is more clear then using other functions like the "authenticated" ones suggested before.

Comment: but why do I need to pass a `Request $request` instance? It gives me an error saying no request instance given

Comment: okay I removed the request parameters and tried again, but now I get this error `Route [/home] not defined.` I am positive that I have a /home route in my web.php

Comment: @sapnesNaik Do you have a named route?  You can use ```return route('home', $arguments);``` for example in your redirectTo function

Comment: @SapneshNaik you do not have to use the `$request` object. It should be injected any ways, but I may be wrong. If you do not have a named route (always preferred and comfortable if in future you would make some "restyle" at the pretty URLs), you can just `redirect('/home')`

Comment: the redirectTo method expects a route('routeName'), without the redirect()->

Answer (score 0):

you can set a method redirectTo() with your custom logic in your LoginController. That method will be called first in redirectPath() from trait RedirectsUsers.

hope it helps
CV

Answer (score 0):

simply you can do with get params, `/home?your_data='blabla'&another_data='blabla'`
and after that use that params in controller to show in view.
But in laravel you can do this more pretty;

```
Route('home{notification?}','YourController@yourAction');
```

and in YourController you shoud do

```
public function yourAction($notification = null) {
   if(isset($notification) {
//do something with notification
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing this function in your LoginController"

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    $notification = array(
                    'message' => 'User okay', 
                    'alert_type' => 'success',
                  );



return Redirect::route('user')->with('notification', $notification);
}
```

Hope it helps.